# Need to return two table types in oracle function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to create one function which will return two table type in output.

Function will be like below:

```
create or replace function function_name (id number) RETURN ... ... ..
as

type i_conID is table of number;
type i_cov_lineID is table of number;

v_conid i_conID;
v_cov_lineid i_cov_lineID;

cursor p_cursor_name (id number) is 
SELECT /*+ parallel(64)*/ con_id,cov_lineid
                      FROM table_name where sava_id  like '%'||id||'%';

   begin
   open p_cursor_name(id);
   loop
   fetch p_cursor_name bulk collect into v_conid, v_cov_lineid;
   exit when p_cursor_name%notfound;
end loop;
   return .. ..
   end ;
```

Here i need output for both  v_conid, v_cov_lineid.

I can't create procedure, as we need to call in select statement.

Comment: You can create a object type in your schema, that has both table types as member variables and use that.

Comment: can you please give hints of code for both table types as member variables

Comment: Its not a wise decision to use out parameter with functions in oracle as they are only meant for the calculations.

Comment: is there any other way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code example how you can create the object type and use it with your example:

**Create Type:**

```sql
CREATE TYPE test_type AS object
  (conid      sys.odcinumberlist
  ,cov_lineid sys.odcinumberlist)
/
```

**Your function:**

```sql
create or replace function function_name (id number) RETURN test_type
as
  res test_type;
BEGIN
  SELECT /*+ parallel(64)*/ con_id,cov_lineid
    BULK COLLECT INTO res.conid, res.cov_lineid
    FROM table_name where sava_id  like '%'||id||'%';

  RETURN res;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for giving this hints :)